# Trigger a function on date change

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have an HTML app with a jQuery DatePicker calendar.
[My calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVhYM.png)

At the launch of the application, today's date is automatically selected.

What I would like to do is to change the date at the date change. For example we are September 11, and I would like to select September 12 at midnight.

The selected date is just a CSS class on the current day.

So I need to execute this function at everyday midnight

```js
// Get current day
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var day = ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day; //output 11

// Add CSS class
$('.calendar a:contains("'+day+'")').addClass('selected');
```

It's possible with jQuery/Javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [setInterval Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```js
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var day = d<10?'0'+ d: d; //output 11
$('div:contains("'+day+'")').addClass('selected');
// Add CSS class


setInterval(function(){ 
  d = date.getDate();
  day = d<10?'0'+ d: d; //output 11
  $('div:contains("'+day+'")').addClass('selected');
}, 60000);
```

```css
.selected{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like to do this automatically, not by clicking on a element

Comment: This is for repeating the code every 60 seconds. You can increase or decreasing

Comment: Oh I understand now, thanks ! I put the topic as resolved :)